# WordAddIn get document handle

Tags: c#, handle, word-addins

I need to get the `Win32Window` (Handle) of the current active Document.

This is what I am currently using:

```
NativeWindow Win32Parent = new NativeWindow()
                         .AssignHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);
```

this works, but because of this piece of code Word does restart every time after I close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. If somebody cares about the Solution:

```
Control control = Control.FromHandle((IntPtr)this.Application.ActiveWindow.Hwnd);
```